# How to declare flow type for named exports?

Tags: javascript, flowtype, flow-typed

I have a file with a default export and some other named exports.

```
  module.exports = function1;
  exports.names= [];
  exports.getStrings = getStrings;
```

`function1` and `getString` functions are defined.

Now, in the `.flow` file i want to declare the types of these variables.

```
declare module.function1: (param: ?(string | number)) => null | number;
declare exports.names: $ReadOnlyArray<string>;
declare exports.getStrings: () => {[string]: string};
```

This is giving flow parse error. I have referred to the flow documentation but couldn’t find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
declare export default {
  (param: ?(string | number)): null | number,
  names: $ReadOnlyArray<string>,
  getStrings: () => {[string]: string},
};
```

Comment: Can I get the CommonJS equivalent? I don't intend to use the ES syntex.Thanks!

Comment: Found the answer. Thanks

Comment: @DhruvTailor could you share it here so that I can edit my answer to add the CommonJS syntax? You can also edit my answer directly if you prefer